# Remesh method in CGAL

Tags: graphics, cgal

I have a low-quality mesh, I want to remesh it but keeping the topology(only adjust the vertex position, keep vertex size, face unchanged). Is there an exist method could do this in CGAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [remesher](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Surface_mesher/Chapter_main.html) in CGAL. However, it will recreate a surface with its own vertices and faces number, depending on the criteria you ask for. You can give it a try by compiling the Surface_mesher demo or using the precompiled windows demo (you need [this](http://www.cgal.org/demo/4.1/surface_mesher.zip) and [this](http://www.cgal.org/demo/4.1/CGAL-demoDLLs.zip)).